# Matplotlib: ticks AutoLocator - Start and end axis on major tick

Tags: python, matplotlib, ticker

I am setting the x axis of my graph using:

```
ax.set_xlim(limit_x_min, limit_x_max)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(AutoLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator())
```

For `limit_x_min=-12`, `limit_x_max=12` it looks nice with the x axis going from -12 to 12.

For `limit_x_min=-5.3`, `limit_x_max=5.3` it is difficult to read where the axis starts and ends. I would like it to range from -6 to 6.

In the same way for `limit_x_min=-1.6e-2`, `limit_x_max=1.6e-2`, I would like the x axis to range from -2.0e-2 to 2.0e-2.

How can I set `AutoLocator` to have the x axis starting and ending on a major tick? I try some rounding but it is tricky as I need to keep the power.

Comment: The locators will never change the x limits. They just try to find suitable positions for the tick marks, taking into account a broad range of situations.  How they work by default is a result of many decades of experimenting and fine-tuning.  What you are suggesting might be quite complicated to get to work consistently.

Comment: Doesn't sound like you want to change the locator, but instead just round the axis limits before using `set_xlim`. There are lots of resources online about rounding to a certain number of significant figures, which I think is what you want here

Comment: I already tried to round the numbers I pass to the limits but it does not seems to work as it needs to be rounded depending on the visible ticks which are set with `AutoLocator`.